# datepicker show days in one and hide days in another

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using two datepickers in my page. One datepicker should show days, months and year, 
and the other should show only month and year.

I had tried some methods like the following. 
**I had tried changing css.**

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
    display: none;
}
```

But this affect both the datepickers.

**I had tried calling a function onClick.**

```
$('.month-picker').click(function(){
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').css('display','none');
});
```

When this function hide the ui-datepicker-calendar class, it shows a gap between ui-datepicker-header and the input box.

Please help me to solve the problem. Thanking you in advance.

The `jsfiddle` is added too

Comment: Please include codes in your question. See [Prevent posts with links to jsfiddle and no code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)

Comment: This question makes no sense? What exactly are you trying to do!

Comment: What do you need to do actually ?

Comment: Your question is nor clear . What you want to do ?

Comment: I thin Eugine wants the second picker showing month and year only. He does not want to have dates displayed as he is NOT interested in date selection. Only month and a year.

Comment: In short words, this is what I want. I want one datepicker with month and year, and one with day,  month and year. using css or jquery I am not able to hide ".ui-datepicker-calendar" because it will hide ".ui-datepicker-calendar" in both datepickers. I am looking for any other methoids.

Comment: jQuery UI team said "The datepicker will not work without days being clicked. There is only one one choice named monthpicker, which will serve best for this criteria". http://lucianocosta.info/jquery.mtz.monthpicker/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this,

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
        },
        beforeShow: function (dateText, inst) { $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').hide(); },
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) { $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide(); }
    });

 add withoutDay class to input elements and add below jquery

 $(".withoutDay").focus(function () {
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with the below approach:

```
$(function() {
$('.date-picker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
        var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
    }
});
```

});

Here's the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9pJk/) for the same.

**Edit**

Corrected for custom sytle. Please check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcgupta17/pDuUZ/1/) now.

Comment: I have two datepickers, one with days and other without days. 
adding style will affect the both datepickers. http://jsfiddle.net/r9pJk/1

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha!! After a couple of trial and error I think I found a work around.  Add an click event handler like this

```
$('.month-picker').on('click', function() {
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').hide();    
});
```

However it still need to be carved.

Check it in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/57VZM/7/)

Comment: @Eugine Joseph Check my updated answer and share your thoughts.

Comment: thanks friend, it is working but when clicking below the datepicker header, the days table are shown for a second. is there anyway to change that?